# pgloader is creating the schema and table but not populating the data

Tags: pgloader

I'm trying to get pgloader to take the inline csv and input into my postgres database. Right now the table is getting created with the schema however there is no data.

This is my code in my .load file

```
    FROM inline (x, y, a, b, c, "camelCase")
    INTO postgresql://"connection string" (x, y, a, b, c, "camelCase")
    
    WITH truncate,
        skip header = 1,
        fields optionally enclosed by '"',
        fields escaped by double-quote,
        fields terminated by ','

     SET client_encoding to 'latin1',
        work_mem to '12MB',
        standard_conforming_strings to 'on'

   BEFORE LOAD DO
    $$ drop table if exists csv; $$,
    $$ create table csv (
        a bigint,
        b bigint,
        c char(2),
        "camelCase" text
       );
    $$;

"2.6.190.56","2.6.190.63","33996344","33996351","GB","United Kingdom"
"3.0.0.0","4.17.135.31","50331648","68257567","US","United States"
```

[and this was the verbose error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nTze.png)

Can someone tell me what is causing this error? Ive been stuck for a few days now